# Javascript: find array by name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some js arrays and I want to find the arrays by name. for example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3];
arr2 = [3,4,5];
```

And access them like this:

```
var intNum = 2;
var arrName = 'arr' + intNum;

arrName[0]; // equals 3
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window['arr'+intNum]
```

so

```
arr1 = [1,2,3];
arr2 = [3,4,5];
intNum=2;
alert(window['arr'+intNum][1]); //will alert 4
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not array access, it's object access. Not to mention this example only works if the arrays are in global scope.

Comment: I'm going to have to give this answer the tick as it was the method I used. Basically, I had arrays that were being generated in the document, so they were in global scope. Gotta give a nod to Sean Kinsey (and discussion) for a more robust solution, as well as helping me understand what I'm using. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible but I would suggest you place these arrays as properties of an object, that makes it a lot easier

```
var arrays {
    arr1 : [1,2,3],
    arr2 : [4,5,6]
}

var arrNum = 2;
var arr = arrays["arr" + arrNum] // arrays.arr2
```

Properties of objects can be accessed both using the `.` operator and as named items using the `["propname"]` notation.

Using `eval` or resorting to using the above trick on `window` is not advised.

Eval'ing is normally a sign of ill constructed code, and using window relies on window being the Variable Object of the global scope - this is not part of any spec and will not necessarily work across browsers.

Comment: why is the window "trick" not advisable (I am sure all the major FW developers in the js world would like to know that)

Comment: Because you rely on window being the Variable Object of the global scope - this is not part of any spec and will not necessarily work across browsers.

Comment: If you're worried about `window` not being the global object, you can call a standalone function that just returns `this`. Of course, at that point, it would probably be better just to use your suggestion and put them in an object.